# R Script Web API Post Method

Tags: r

I have this code to get a response from a Web API

```
require("httr")
r <- POST("https://example.com/API/Bulk/2.0/Contacts/exports/",
      config = list("Authorization"="Basic abc==","Accept"="application/json",
                    "body"= "{  'name':'JB Test - Contact Lead Score Export','fields':{'ID':'{{Contact.Field(ContactIDEXT)}}'}}"))
r
```

I get the following error message:

> Response [example.com/API/Bulk/2.0/Contacts/exports/] Date: 2018-03-02 12:49 Status: 400 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Size: 175 B { "failures":[{"field":"name","constraint":"Must be a string value, at least 1 character and at most 100 characters long."},{"field":"fields","constraint":"Is required."}]} 
>   I am getting failure message.
>   Whats wrong in this code?

Comment: Please post the failure message!

Comment: Response [https://example.com/API/Bulk/2.0/Contacts/exports/]
  Date: 2018-03-02 12:49
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 175 B
{
"failures":[{"field":"name","constraint":"Must be a string value, at least 1 character and at most 100 characters long."},{"field":"fields","constraint":"Is required."}]}

Comment: Welcome to SO. I added your error message to your question. You can use the edit function to change your post and to supply additional information.

Comment: @AntonyRajesh I don't know R, but JSON requires to use double quotes in strings and you are using single quotes. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @Paul tried with double quote, but no success. Anyway Thanks :)